# Awk include "any of the following" into one print statemrnt

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm writing a bash parser, with one of the functions below. I'm trying to search for everal codes in column 11 for `any of the following` sort of logic.

```
Disconnected () {

disconnections=$(awk '$9=="421" & $9=="221" &  $9=="511" {print}' ${source_file} | sed 's/[^0-9]*/1/g' | wc -l)
echo "there have been $disconnections timeouts or disconnects"
VerifyExitCode

}
```

I have also tried:

```
Disconnected () {

disconnections=$(awk '$9=="421" || $9=="221" || $9=="511" {print}' ${source_file} | sed 's/[^0-9]*/1/g' | wc -l)
echo "there have been $disconnections timeouts or disconnects"
VerifyExitCode

}
```

GOAL: to find the SUM of all occurrences where the code 421, 221, and 511 appears. So if there are 12 lines that 421 appears, 10 lines where 221 appears and 3 where 521 appears, it should print out `there have been 25 timeouts or disconnects`.

I'm lost as to why it's not adding them up. One gives me a syntax error, and one gives me the total amount LESS those times. (This exact coding working beautifully for a single `$disconnect` code, just not 3!!)

I've tried looking at man awk, and I've tried a few similar questions here on stackexchange but can't find the answer. I'm certain it will take one of you gurus about 30 seconds flat to find the answer though. Thanks!

EDIT - adding sample input log.

```
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]dele  /P0016/pCR37558666_0.pdf    -   250 -   -   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1190]user  GCO\johnsmith   -   331 -   -   -   9342        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1190]pass  ******* -   221 -   -   -   9342        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]sent  /P0016/pCR37558672_0.pdf    -   226 -   14141   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]dele  /P0016/pCR37558672_0.pdf    -   250 -   -   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]sent  /P0016/pCR37558678_0.pdf    -   226 -   14800   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]dele  /P0016/pCR37558678_0.pdf    -   250 -   -   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1190]quit  -   -   421 -   -   -   9342        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   -   [1190]ssh_disconnect    disconnect_by_application   -   511 -   -   -   9342        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]sent  /P0016/pCR37558682_0.pdf    -   226 -   14132   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]dele  /P0016/pCR37558682_0.pdf    -   250 -   -   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]sent  /P0016/pCR37558690_0.pdf    -   226 -   14128   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]dele  /P0016/pCR37558690_0.pdf    -   511 -   -   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]sent  /P0016/pCR37558694_0.pdf    -   226 -   14168   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]dele  /P0016/pCR37558694_0.pdf    -   250 -   -   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]sent  /P0016/pCR37558696_0.pdf    -   226 -   14170   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]dele  /P0016/pCR37558696_0.pdf    -   250 -   -   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]sent  /P0016/pCR37558700_0.pdf    -   226 -   14176   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]dele  /P0016/pCR37558700_0.pdf    -   250 -   -   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1175]user  GCO\johnsmith   -   221 -   -   -   9340        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1175]pass  ******* -   230 -   -   -   9340        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\stmap   [1752]user  GCO\stmasftp    -   331 -   -   -   8221        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\stmap   [1752]pass  ******* -   230 -   -   -   8221        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]sent  /P0016/pCR37558704_0.pdf    -   226 -   32898   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]dele  /P0016/pCR37558704_0.pdf    -   250 -   -   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:01 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]sent  /P0016/pCR37558706_0.pdf    -   226 -   14111   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:01 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]dele  /P0016/pCR37558706_0.pdf    -   250 -   -   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:01 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\chubbs  [186982]user    GCO\chwbsftpsvc -   331 -   -   -   8234        
4/13/2016   5:00:01 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\chubbs  [186982]pass    ******* -   230 -   -   -   8234        
4/13/2016   5:00:01 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]sent  /P0016/pCR37558708_0.pdf    -   226 -   14918   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:01 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]dele  /P0016/pCR37558708_0.pdf    -   250 -   -   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:01 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1175]sent  /P0018/PCR38150024_0.pdf    -   226 -   19845   -   9340        
4/13/2016   5:00:01 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1175]dele  /P0018/PCR38150024_0.pdf    -   250 -   -   -   9340        
4/13/2016   5:00:01 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]sent  /P0016/pCR37558710_0.pdf    -   521 -   14198   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:01 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]dele  /P0016/pCR37558710_0.pdf    -   250 -   -   -   9341        
4/13/2016   5:00:01 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1175]sent  /P0018/PCR38150026_0.pdf    -   226 -   25546   -   9340
```

The result of the two awk statements below:

`Disconnected () {

disconnections=$(awk '$9 ~ /^(421|221|511)$/{c++} END{print c}' ${source_file})
echo "there have been $disconnections timeouts or disconnects"
VerifyExitCode

}`

and

`Disconnected () {

disconnections=$(awk '$9=="421" || $9=="221" || $9=="511" {count++} END {print count}' ${source_file} )
echo "there have been $disconnections timeouts or disconnects"
VerifyExitCode

}`

model is (running the bash -x option):

`Disconnected
++ awk '$9 ~ /^(421|221|511)$/{c++} END{print c}' /root/testlog
+ disconnections=5
+ echo 'there have been 5 timeouts or disconnects'
there have been 5 timeouts or disconnects
+ VerifyExitCode
+ local EXITCODE=0
+ '[' 0 '!=' 0 ']'`

This should respond as 4.

Thanks!

Comment: can you add a line from input?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to count the number of lines for the given condition

```
awk '$9=="421" || $9=="221" || $9=="511" {count++}
                                     END {print count}' file
```

you can also write it more compactly

```
awk '$9 ~ /^(421|221|511)$/{c++} END{print c}' file
```

when I try this on your sample input

```
$ awk '$9 ~ /^(421|221|511)$/{c++} END{print c}' file
5
```

to check what lines matched

```
$ awk '$9 ~ /^(421|221|511)$/' file

4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1190]pass  ******* -   221 -   -   -   9342
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1190]quit  -   -   421 -   -   -   9342
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   -   [1190]ssh_disconnect    disconnect_by_application   -   511 -   -   -   9342
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1178]dele  /P0016/pCR37558690_0.pdf    -   511 -   -   -   9341
4/13/2016   5:00:00 192.168.33.118  -   GCO\johnsmith   [1175]user  GCO\johnsmith   -   221 -   -   -   9340
```

Comment: Neither of these quite scratches the itch.... Not sure why, but the count should be 251, and I'm getting `1` with the first code, and 0 with the second code. 
`Disconnected () {
disconnections=$(awk '$9=="421" || $9=="221" || $9=="511" {count++} END {print count}' ${source_file} | sed 's/[^0-9]*/1/g' | wc -l)
echo "there have been $disconnections timeouts or disconnects"
VerifyExitCode
}`
and 
`Disconnected () {
disconnections=$(awk '$9 ~ /^(421|221|511)$/{c++} END{print c}' ${source_file} | sed 's/[^0-9]*/1/g' | wc -l)
echo` :(CUT DUE TO CHARACTER LIMIT - but this isn't as relevant).

Comment: please post a sample input file so that it can be used to verify the scripts.  You just need to use the `awk` script which already does the counting.  Remove `sed` and `wl`

Comment: I removed the sed and wc -l and for both of your examples, I'm still getting the inverse of what it should be (43,731 instead of 251)

I'll edit and post a portion of the log shortly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: see my results on your sample input.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'm getting a different number. Thanks!

Comment: Use the last script with the test file and check what records you are getting.